# How to integrate vega chart to stencil js component?

Tags: node.js, vega-lite, vega, stenciljs, stencil-component

I am trying to create a stencil js component using vega chart, according to vega manual i installed 3 packages:

```
npm install vega
npm install vega-lite
npm install vega-embed
```

and trying to import

`import { Vega } from 'vega'`

and get this.

> Module '"vega"' has no exported member 'Vega'

Did anyone manage to integrate vega chart into stencil js?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So what does the error ``Module "vega" has no exported member 'Vega'`` mean? This way of importing Vega is not mentioned in the vega documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the usage docs](https://vega.github.io/vega/usage/):

> **Using Vega with a bundler.** If you use Vega with a bundler like rollup.js, you can import Vega as a module.
>
> `import * as vega from "vega";`

Note that if you're using it in a component with Shadow DOM enabled you will probably need to pass Vega, in the `container` configuration, a DOM node instead of a CSS selector:

```
class MyComponent {
  container: HTMLDivElement;

  componentDidLoad() {
    new vega.View(vega.parse(spec), {
      renderer:  'canvas',  // renderer (canvas or svg)
      container: this.container,   // parent DOM container
    });

    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={el => this.container = el}></div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Thomas! It's working. I also found another way with using 

import embed from 'vega-embed'

componentDidLoad() {
   embed('#viz', this.spec, {actions:false})
}

And now trying to figure out which way is more common